# Invoice number displayed blank

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a simple inventory system using c#.

When I am generating the invoice number, the form is loaded but it doesn't  show anything.

It is an auto-incremented invoice number; order is completed incrementally by 1.
For example, starting at E-0000001, after order we expect E-0000002. I don't understand why it is blank.

No error displayed. I tried to debug the code but I couldn't find what's wrong.

```
 public void invoiceno()
 {
     try
     {
         string c;
         sql = "SELECT MAX(invoid) FROM sales";
         cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
         var maxInvId = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;

         if (maxInvId == null)
         {
             label4.Text = "E-000001";
         }
         else
         {
             int intVal = int.Parse(maxInvId.Substring(2, 6));
             intVal++;
             label4.Text = String.Format("E-{0:000000}", intVal);
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.Write(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: does it throw an exception?

Comment: no exception thrown

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: you to open the connection, IE `cmd.Open()` before using  `ExecuteScalar`, you view an example at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Ensure that no other place in your code is resetting the text value of the label after calling invoiceno(). Also, check if the label's visible property is set to true.

Answer (score 3):

Let's *extract a method* - `NextInvoiceId` - we

1. Open connection
2. Execute query
3. Obtain next invoice number

Code:

```
private int NextInvoiceNumber() {
  //TODO: put the right connection string here
  using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHere)) {
    conn.Open();

    string sql = 
      @"SELECT MAX(invoid) 
          FROM sales";

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
      var raw = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;

      return raw == null 
        ? 1                                        // no invoces, we start from 1
        : int.Parse(raw.Trim('e', 'E', '-')) + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Then we can easily call it:

```
public void invoiceno() {
  label4.Text = $"E-{NextInvoiceNumber():d6}";
}
```

**Edit:** You should not *swallow* exceptions:

```
try 
{
    ... 
}
// Don't do this!
catch (Exception ex) // All the exceptions will be caught and...
{
    // printed on the Console...
    // Which is invisible to you, since you develop Win Forms (WPF) application
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    Console.Write(ex.StackTrace);
}
```

let system *die* and inform you that something *got wrong*